# Encapsulating unicode string with quotes

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to encapsulate my uncicode variable in quotes.

```
q = u'turtle'
print(q) prints turtle
```

The goal is to encapsulate `turtle` inside the unicode type with quotes so it looks like this `q = u'"turtle"'` or prints as `"turtle"` but still retain its unicode type.

How do i go about inserting that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply format a unicode string:

```
u'"%s"' % turtle
```